# cumulative sum over time period

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

my dataframe has the following structure:

```
 date_today = dt.datetime.now()
 size=20
 df = pd.DataFrame({"usd": pd.Series(np.random.randint(1,100,size))*10,
               "sent": dt.datetime.now(),
               "temp":np.random.randint(0,15, size=size)
              })
df.sent += df.temp.map(dt.timedelta)
df.temp = np.random.randint(10,25, size=size)
df["reminder"] = df.sent + df.temp.map(dt.timedelta)
df.temp = np.random.randint(1,65, size=size)
df["completed"] = df.reminder + df.temp.map(dt.timedelta)
df.loc[df['temp']%3 == 0, ['reminder']] = [""]
df.loc[df['temp']%2 == 0, ['completed']] = [""]
df=df[["usd", "sent", "reminder", "completed"]]
```

usd is the money I am requesting (numeric), the other columns are datetime (when I requested, when I sent a reminder, and when I got the money; last two nullable).
I have also created the following list of quarters of a month:

```
date_index = []
previous_date=""
for m in range(0,14):
    month = (m%12)+1
    year = m//12
    current_date = dt.date(2019+year, month, 1)
    if previous_date:
        timedelta = current_date-previous_date
        date_index.append(previous_date+1*timedelta/4)
        date_index.append(previous_date+2*timedelta/4)
        date_index.append(previous_date+3*timedelta/4)
    date_index.append(current_date)
    previous_date = current_date
```

I would like to obtain a dataframe with the following structure:

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame(columns=["date","sent_amount","reminder_amount","completed_amount"])
```

where df_result.date column is the date_index sequence from the previous point, sent_amount is the sum of df.amount column for records where df.sent columns is < df_result.date, reminder_amount is the sum of df.amount column for records where df.reminder columns is < df_result.date. I can achieve it with a loop, but I would be eager to learn how to make my code slimmer. If you have any suggestion about the random dataframe creation or the quarters of a month list, they are also very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `melt` the DataFrame, `cut` dates into date ranges from `date_index`, then group by the combination of variable (completed/reminder/sent) + date, `sum` up `usd` amounts, then unstack it back into columns and `cumsum` it to get cumulative sums:

```
x = df.melt('usd', value_name='date')
x['date'] = pd.cut(x['date'], pd.to_datetime(date_index)).apply(lambda x: x.right)
x['variable'] += '_amount'

df_result = x.dropna().groupby(['variable', 'date'])['usd'].sum().unstack(0, 0).sort_index().cumsum()

print(df_result)
```

Output:

```
variable    completed_amount  reminder_amount  sent_amount
date                                                      
2019-03-16                 0                0         3180
2019-03-24                 0                0         8840
2019-04-01                 0             1700        10350
2019-04-08                 0             3230        10350
2019-04-16                 0             6200        10350
2019-04-23               320             6860        10350
2019-05-01              1170             6860        10350
2019-05-16              2300             6860        10350
2019-06-01              5130             6860        10350
2019-06-08              5710             6860        10350
```